Is there a way to get decimal accuracy to 19 spots post decimal?
I have the following fields:
Field1:
0.00
Field2:
94777.58
Field3:
223000.00

FinalNumber = (Field1 + Field2)/Field3

All fields are Decimal(11,2).
Trying to get this FinalNumber value to 19 spots post the decimal in accuracy using SQL server.
Tried using CAST( ( Num1 + Num2 ) / Num3 ) AS Decimal(31,19) but it's not working correctly. Can someone please help?
UPDATE:
Used CONVERT(NUMERIC(31,19),((Field1 + Field2)/Fields3)) and got value to 19 digits but the last 5 digits are filling in random 0's.
Looking to get precisely the following number below:
FinalNumber = 0.4250115695067264573
Currently looking like this: 0.4250115695067200000
Any suggestions?

Column data types?

What do these values represent such that you need 19 digits of accuracy/significance?

Your CAST() expression, as-is, is invalid: the AS decimal part needs to be inside the CAST() parentheses, like so: CAST( ( ( Num1 + Num2 ) / Num3 ) AS decimal(31,19) ) - but that's still redundant because Num1, Num2, and Num3 need to be promoted to high-precision decimal(p,s) before you evaluate the + and / operators.

And how do I promote to high precision?

CAST them each individual inside your calculation (CAST(num1 AS DECIMAL(31,19) + CAST(num2 AS DECIMAL(31,19)))/CAST(num as DECIMAL(31,19))

Note that tables have columns, not fields.

@jarlh Uhm ackshully relations of tuples have attributes, not "columns"

@Dai, that's when talking relational model. I speak SQL. 'The terms column, field, and attribute refer to structural components of tables, row types, and structured
types, respectively, in analogous fashion. As the structure of a table consists of one or more columns, so does the structure of a row type consist of one or more fields and that of a structured type one or more attributes.' (ISO/IEC 9075-2:2023(E), section 4.15 Columns, fields, and attributes)

@jarlh "so does the structure of a row type consist of one or more fields" - doesn't that contradict yourself?

@Dau, I wouldn't say so. E,g. select (1, 2) c from ... returns one column (a row-type column), consisting of two fields. Still column <> field. And create type u as (a1 int, a2 int); select new u() from ... will give you one column (a structured type), having two attributes.

You're now converting the end result to number of decimals which makes little sense. You should convert the operands themselves. It's like math, you can't get higher precision from lower precision intermediates

Determining the result precision of a NUMERIC division is complicated. See the Remarks section in the Precision, scale, and length documentation. To get the desired result precision, you have to carefully type both the dividend and divisor. For a division with types NUMERIC(p1,s1) / NUMERIC(p2,s2), the result precision = p1 - s1 + s2 + max(6, s1 + p2 + 1) and scale = max(6, s1 + p2 + 1)  However, if the calculated precision exceeds 38, both precision and scale will be reduced. ...

(...continued) For example, the calculation (CAST(Field1 + Field2 AS NUMERIC(10,2))) / CAST(Field3 as NUMERIC(16,2)) will yield a scale of 19. So will (CAST(Field1 + Field2 AS NUMERIC(12,6))) / CAST(Field3 as NUMERIC(12,6)).  But (CAST(Field1 + Field2 AS NUMERIC(30,6))) / CAST(Field3 as NUMERIC(12,6)) will cause a reduced scale, because the calculated precision exceeds 38.  You will need to carefully choose values that are appropriate for the range of values that you expect in your query. See this db<>fiddle.

The linked duplicate answer is not really a duplicate, as that question involved unintentional integer division, and the suggested answers (such as casting to float) are not detailed enough to address getting a high degree of fractional precision requested by this question. (Float will only yield about 16 digits.)

After seeing that your source values are Decimal(11,2), you should be able to safely use the expression (Field1 + Field2) / CAST(Field3 as Decimal(16,2)). The result is 0.4250115695067264573 with type Decimal(31,19). See this db<>fiddle.

Addressing your edit; what's wrong with ROUND? Though shouldn't it be 0.4250115695067300000?
